# Correctly Syncing Material-UI Tab component with React Router and Nested Tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have been reading a lot of past questions and answers as well as experimenting continuously, but I feel like I might be barking down the wrong path...

If I had a page that contained tabs like so:

```
<Tabs value={location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') == -1 ? 0 : location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))}>
  <Tab label="Tab 1" value='/tab1' />
  <Tab label="Tab 2" value='/tab2'>
     <Tab2Contents />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>

function Tab2Contents(){
   
   return (<Tabs value={location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') == -1 ? 0 : location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))}>
  <Tab label="Detail" value='/detail' />
  <Tab label="Info" value='/info'>
     <Tab2Contents />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>)
}
```

This may work on a simplistic case however if the path structure gets deeper so it's no longer just:

http://somewebsite/home/tab2

Rather Tab2Contents ends up having a list of items, and when you click on the item it shows details of the item grouped in another set of tabs which will yield a path structure like:

http://somewebsite/home/tab2/details

Obviously the Main set of tabs (Tab1, Tab2) would no longer match correctly.

Is there anyway to actually solve this at all? Every solution online seems to require the tab click handling to set states, but it obviously doesn't work too well if someone was to navigate to that url, it would expect both the Home page's Tab's would be highlighted along with the Details Tab.

Comment: I would need to see more of what you’re attempting to do to make a better suggestion. Having said that, what are you ultimately trying to achieve? You should probably start by storing your value in state.

Comment: Provide us a minimal & complete code example of your problem. I don't see any code of nested tabs but question title talks about that. I don't want to make assumptions of your code.

Comment: @andrewkeithly What I am trying to achieve is, the main page had tabs, then within one of the tabs it will have another set of tabs, I've updated my question of this.

Comment: @AjeetShah have updated it, as you can see the Tab2Contents returns another set of tabs, but now the url would be something like

http://somewebsite/home/tab2/detail

Which makes the parent tab to break in selection of the value for Tabs.

Comment: Don't use `location.pathname.substring`, instead use [URL params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params) or [search params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters).